# How to train a model when there is too much training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have an RNN and way too much training data. Iterating through the data in its entirety will take years. Right now I have two options for training:

**1. Do one pass over as much data as possible**

**2. Find a select portion of the data and train for multiple epochs on it**

Which one is better and why?

Comment: This is not opinion based, I disagree with the hold. There is scientific reasoning behind the answer to this question.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan, whatever hold put on the question is irrelevant. This question has nothing to do with programming and doesn’t belong on this site

Comment: Okay, I reacted to the closure because "primarily opinion based". That is not true. It might be more of a statistics question than programming, that is true.

Comment: It is not  a matter of opinion, the answer I posted is well known and has a large literature supporting it.   And it is a necessary part of programming these kinds of methods were there is not a large data set.   Look for "leave one out" and "leave N out" methods. However, I agree with locking it, the answers are not likely to improve with time.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is far superior, supposing the data has the same quality throughout.

The reason being is that it helps avoid overfitting. One of the biggest issues in ML is that you have a limited amount of data to train on, and the networks tend to *overfit* that is learn the specific of the set of data instead of generalizing to the problem intended.

Never repeating the data is actually the ideal situation for training.

The only caveat being is if you have the labels very accurately set in certain parts and more sloppily done in others - in that case sticking with the better quality data *might* be better.

Comment: Peter, your answer seems surprising. Would you not agree that in the limiting case of training on all of your data, you are more likely to overfit your model?  (Presumably, the intent is to use the network for data beyond the training set.)  Did we perhaps understand the question differently, or perhaps I misunderstand something in your answer? – DrM just now   edit

Comment: Well, the premise of the question is that he cannot possibly go through all training data, because he has too much data. This is very much unlike anything I've ever faced in ML. 100% of the time there is too little data and you try to do some magic to counteract overfitting. The best way to achieve that is to never use the same piece of data twice. Supposing his data is correctly labeled throughout, this will lead to superior performance on unknown data as opposed to repeating a small subset many times. [cont'd]

Comment: In other words, if you can only train on 1M exemplars (limit imposed by available computing resources and time, _not the amount of data_) then it's better if those 1M are all different, than if any is repeated.

Comment: Yes, selection without replacement is clear.  Nonetheless, he is forced into using a subset of his data.  So, surely he is going to take another subset of the data and test his result.  Once he has done that, it would seem that he needs to do it  a few times.  So he might as well run cross validation.

Comment: This is what I know cross-validation to be: [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) It is possible to do that here, but not necessary, because you have a deluge of data. Cross validation is another useful tool for dealing with too few data... :)

Answer (score 2):

The question is asked in general terms, so the following is also in general terms.  I hope this contributes something to helping you with your specific problem.

One approach would be a variant of cross validation.  You randomly select some portion of the data, and evaluate the result on a second portion of the data. Repeat the entire process until you satisfy your convergence criteria or exhaust your count.  The convergence criteria might be something like getting the same or similar network at some rate.  You can do this in either of two modes, allowing or not allowing reuse of the data.

A second point to keep in mind is that your execution time depends on the length of your "feature vectors" or whatever serves that function in your application.  Selecting the important components of your feature vectors, both reduces the processing time and also can help the training be more successful. Scikit learn has a function SelectKBest() that may be helpful for this.